# sqlite-net for UWP

Tags: uwp, sqlite-net

I am testing SQLite.net for my UWP 10 App. I have added the SQLite extension for Universal Windows Platform(i.e the required .vsix) to my project as reference.
Also from nuget I have installed the sqlite-net nuget package.

Yet I am unable to add a refernce to SQLite -net functions in my project. Also I cant see any additional SQLite.cs or SQLiteAsync.cs added to the project.
Do I need some additional configurations?

Also is SQLite.Net-PCL better than sqlite-net.If yes then in what terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuget packages for UWP apps do not allow you to add code files to the project.  You will either need to the SQLite.Net-PCL or entity framework 7 RC (soon to be Enityframework core 1.0)

Answer (score 3):

It works fine on my side with SQLite.Net-PCL and SQLite.Net.Async-PCL in a UWP app.

This is how I used this two packages:

- Install the SQLite.Net-PCL package and SQLite.Net.Async-PCL from Nuget
- Choose "Extensions and Updates..." from "tool", and in "Online" searched "sqlite", find "SQLite for Universal App Platform" and install it.
  [image]
- Right click `References` of your project, choose "Add Reference", then add "SQLite for Universal App Platform".
  [image]

Here is a [IncrementalLoadingWithSQLite sample](http://1drv.ms/1jJ03Om) I wrote yesterday, the file is kind of large because I have over 600+ pictures in this project.

Comment: It works fine with SQLite.Net-PCL but not with sqlite.Net. These two are different nuget packages.

Comment: Yes, they are two different packages, you are right, I just about to provide a way to use SQLite in an UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a reference SQLite SDK reference to your project and installing the  SQLite.NET PCL package is all you need. You should now have access to SQLiteConnection and all the other classes.

Take a look at this article describing the process step by step: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/09/08/Using-SQLite-on-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add the required references. I did the same mistake at first...

```
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT;
using Windows.Storage;
```

the last one is for getting to the path where the SQLite db is stored in the apps local folder.. 
Additional references like

```
using System.Data.Common;
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
```

will be required for other stuff you wanna do with the db on the app..